# Question about inheritance and OOP c#

Tags: c#, oop

I have a persistent object which for the sake of this question, I'll car CAR class.

```
public class Car
{
   public string model {get;set}
   public int year {get;set}
}
```

Obviously hugely simplified.

Now, as the code developed I naturally created a function which accepts CAR as a parameter. For example:

```
public void PaintCar (Car theCar)
{
  //Does some work
}
```

So far so good, but then I had a scenario where I needed another class, which was very similar to CAR, but car was missing some fields. No problem I thought OOP to the rescue, I'll just inherit from Car, to end up with:

```
public class SuperCar : Car
{
   public string newProp {get;set}
   // and some more properties
}
```

Once again everything looked peachy, until I came across a very useful utility function I was using to populate Cars original properties.

```
Public void SetCarProperties(Car theCar)
{
    //sets the properties for car here
}
```

I thought mmm, I wish I could use that same function to set the properties for my superCar class without needing an override. I also don't want to change the base car definition to include all properties of the superCar class.

At this point I hit a dilemma. The override would work, but it is extra work. Is there a more elegant solution. Basically I want to pass through the superclass to a function that is expecting a base class. Is this possible with c#?

My final code result would be something like :

```
Car myCar = new Car(); 
SetCarProperties(myCar); // ALL GOOD

SuperCar mySuperCar = new SuperCar(); 
SetCarProperties(mySuperCar); // at the moment this function is expecting type Car...
```

Comment: I think it would be more appropriate to have this `SetCarProperties` method in the `Car` class, and have it overridden in the child class `SuperCar`.

Comment: If not, I think the override would be a cleanest solution.

Answer (score 12):

A more elegant solution is to put the function `SetCarProperties` on the `Car` class and override it in `SuperCar` to use `base` to fill `Car`'s properties and some additional code to fill `SuperCar` properties.

Edit: otherwise known as polymorphism.

Comment: Otherwise known as a very elegant solution. Thank you!

Comment: You might even go a step further. Just like a car does not build itself, but rather it is built in a factory, perhaps the polymorphic building behavior might also be expressed in the same way. As in, get a more derived builder as opposed to using a more derived car's method.

Comment: What Anthony Pegram proposes is known as the factory pattern - you may read up on that. It has however the drawback of introducing two parallel inheritance hierarchies

Answer (score 2):

Introduce the override, but have the original call the base class version to set-up the common properties:

```
public void SetCarProperties(Car car)
{
    // set general properties
}

public void SetCarProperties(SuperCar veyron)
{
    this.SetCarProperties((Car) veyron);

    // SuperCar specific properties
}
```

Comment: You've got the hierarchy flipped on its head, the `Car` is the base class here, its method should be called second. More importantly, this isn't polymorphic, so if you have a `SuperCar` exposed as a `Car` (once this snippet is fixed*), it will compile to use the less derived method and skip the method for the more derived class entirely.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram: thanks, fixed. I think I was thrown by the word 'Super'.

Comment: Indeed, it's an unfortunate usage, particularly if you come from a different background (such as Java).

Comment: @Mark H: thanks, but `base` would not work as this is a procedure outside of the class. I've added in the necessary cast. Further evidence that this stuff should all be shunted into Car and SuperCar themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a method in the Car class with protected virtual.So every subclass that wants to set any of its own properties can do this from inside this function.So your code can be as follows:

```
   public class Car
   {
      public string model {get;set}
      public int year {get;set}

      public void SetCarProperties(Car theCar)
      {
          //sets the properties for car here
         ….
        //at the end:
          SetExtraProperties();
       }

      protected virtual void SetExtraProperties()
      {
      }

  }
```

In any sub class that wants to set its own properties , it must override the method as 
follow:

```
    public class SuperCar : Car
     {
      public string newProp {get;set}
       // and some more properties
      protected override void SetExtraProperties()
       {
       this.newProp = "";
        …
       }

     }
```

Answer (score -1):

SuperCar sCar  = car as SuperCar;
if (sCar != null)
{
  set properties on scar;
}

set properties on car;

Comment: Type checking can grow to become unmaintainable. Each time you add a new derived car, you have to come into this method and update it, as well.